# Error not displayed in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I got a problem where errors are not being displayed.

Here is my code

```
   $.ajax({
           url: '{{ url("userposteditajax") }}',
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'post',
          data: {firstname:firstname,lastname:lastname,phone:phone,email:email,address:address,country:country,city:city,password:password,role:role,status:status,id:id},
          success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
            if(data.message == 'Success')
            {
                $('#ajax_submit').prop('disabled', false);

                location.reload();
                $.magnificPopup.close();
            }
            else {
                var errors = data.message;
                 $('#ajax_submit').prop('disabled', false);

                $.each( errors, function( key, value ) {
                // console.log(errors);
                    $('#ajax_error').fadeIn('slow',function(){

                        $('#ajax_error_mess').html(value);

                    });
                });
            }

            },
            error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){

                $('#ajax_submit').prop('disabled', false);
                var errors = jqXhr.responseJSON;
                $.each( errors, function( key, value ) {
                    $('#ajax_error').fadeIn('slow',function(){
                        $('#ajax_error_mess').html(value);
                    });
                });
            }
       });
    return false;
   });
```

My controller code:

```
 $rules = ['firstname' => 'required|max:20',
               'lastname'  => 'required|max:10',

               'phone'     => 'required|max:15',
               'email'     => 'required|email',
               'address'   => 'required',
               'country'   => 'required',
               'city'      => 'required',
               'role'      => 'required',
               'status'    => 'required'];
            $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);
            if( $validator->fails() )
            {           

            $error='';
            $mess = $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray();
            foreach($mess as $row => $val)
             {
                foreach($val as $key )
                {
                    $error .=$key." <br />";
                }
             }

                //return json_encode(array('message'=>$error));
                return Response::json(array('message'=>$error));

            }
```

The error is not displayed even in console.

The output in response I get is

```
 {"message":"The firstname field is required. <br \/>The lastname field is required. <br \/>The email field is required. <br \/>The address field is required. <br \/>"}
```

Comment: We don't have a magic ball in hand. Is there any errors in console ? What is the value in html ? did you get the break in else condition ?

Comment: the error what i get is been given ,nothing is being displayed in console. before  $.each( errors, function( key, value ) {........................} if i print the data in console then the error is displayed in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some modifications of your code.

**Jquery:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{{ url("userposteditajax") }}',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    data: {firstname:firstname,lastname:lastname,phone:phone,email:email,address:address,country:country,city:city,password:password,role:role,status:status,id:id},
    success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
        if(data.success === true)
        {
            $('#ajax_submit').prop('disabled', false);

            location.reload();
            $.magnificPopup.close();
        }
        else {
            $.each(data.errors, function (key, value) {
                //print errors in the console
                console.log('Field name: ' + key + ', Error: ' + value);

            }

        },
        error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){

            $('#ajax_submit').prop('disabled', false);
            var errors = jqXhr.responseJSON;
            $.each( errors, function( key, value ) {
                $('#ajax_error').fadeIn('slow',function(){
                    $('#ajax_error_mess').html(value);
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

**PHP:**

```
$response['success'] = true;

$rules = ['firstname' => 'required|max:20',
        'lastname'  => 'required|max:10',
        'phone'     => 'required|max:15',
        'email'     => 'required|email',
        'address'   => 'required',
        'country'   => 'required',
        'city'      => 'required',
        'role'      => 'required',
        'status'    => 'required'];

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);

if( $validator->fails() )
{           
    $response['success'] = false;
    $response['errors'] = $validator->errors();
    return Response::json($response);
}


return Response::json($response);
```